# sqlite how to update a column automatically from a variable

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I am trying to see if trigger is the function I can use for my situation. I basically want to imitate automatic update feature of Excel like how Sum(A:A) automatically updates and returns the sum. Here is my schema.

```
.schema
CREATE TABLE product (id integer, name text, price integer);
CREATE TABLE sum(total integer);
```

I want to trigger an INSERT/UPDATE command that sums price and inserts the value to total. I have tried the following but syntax error is giving me a headache.

```
CREATE TRIGGER strigger insert on product
begin
INSERT into sum(total) values(sum(price) from product);
end;
```

Is this the right approach? or Do I have to deliberately call an update command from sqlite console or host language?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible to write a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER strigger
AFTER INSERT ON product
BEGIN
    UPDATE sum SET total = (SELECT sum(price) FROM product);
END;
```

But in many cases, it would be a better idea to compute the sum on demand:

```
CREATE VIEW sum AS
SELECT sum(price) AS total FROM product;
```

Comment: Yea, I guess if I am just analyzing/sorting data, making multiple view is easier. Thanks for your help